# Where can I find some examples about google adwords?

Tags: java, google-ads-api

Now I am working on a project about google adwords. I try to follow the steps on the [tutorial page](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/first-request). I have add the dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-ads</groupId>
        <artifactId>ads-lib</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-ads</groupId>
        <artifactId>adwords-axis</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

into the pox.xml file and these client libraries are found in the .m2 repository. But when I try the code such as:

```
 AdWordsUser user = new AdWordsUser();
```

class AdWordsUser cannot be found. Why does this happen since I have followed the guild?

Comment: Have you added the release version as a variable in the POM named RELEASE
when you clean install the project will that execute successfully? and then if its successful make sure that you add the library to the classpath of eclipse as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the new java library, for which the tutorial page doesn't cover.

The [wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ads-java/wiki/MigrationGuide) has more detail, but basically you'll be constructing an AdWordsSession via a builder.

Comment: Thx, I have been stumped by this problem for a whole day and get no answer from the google.